# How to read unicode character from xml into xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, unicode

I'm trying to read a Unicode character from XML input and output to HTML using xslt.

My XML input looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<chart>
  <name>Joe Schmoe</name>
  <nickname>Joe</nickname>
  <symbol>&#x00CD</symbol>
</chart>
```

My xsl stylesheet looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY>
  <h1>Chart Report for <xsl:value-of select="chart/name"/>  </h1>
  <h2>General Characteristics</h2>
  <h3>Social</h3>
  <p>Your nickname is <xsl:value-of select="chart/nickname"/></p>
  <p>Your symbol is <span style="font-family:MyFont"><xsl:value-of select="chart/symbol"/></span></p> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the transform, I get the following error:
  Invalid syntax for a hexadecimal numeric entity reference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need a semicolon after the hex, like so `&#x00CD;`    Without the semicolon, it's not valid XML.

Comment: Note that it's not an XSLT error, it's an XML syntax error. Ben is right.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thanks, guys.